# Dependency Injection on API to API with AutoRest

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, swagger

I been following the [Swagger in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started/) tutorial and I notice the AutoREST code generation. In the tutorial, theres is an API and a DataAPI.

The TodoListAPI is a normal Web API.
The TodoListDataAPI is the one that is connected to a datasource, it is also a Web API and it is being consumed by TodoListAPI.

Using swagger autogerated codes are being imported to the TodoListAPI

```
  partial interface ITodoListDataAPI: IDisposable
    {
        Uri BaseUri
        {
            get; set; 
        }

        ServiceClientCredentials Credentials
        {
            get; set; 
        }

        IToDoList ToDoList
        {
            get; 
        }

  ....


/// this seems to be the interface that is needed to be injected in the Controller
public partial interface IToDoList
 {

      Task<HttpOperationResponse<object>> DeleteByOwnerAndIdWithOperationResponseAsync(string owner, int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(System.Threading.CancellationToken));

      Task<HttpOperationResponse<ToDoItem>> GetByIdByOwnerAndIdWithOperationResponseAsync(string owner, int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(System.Threading.CancellationToken));
```

Then in the ToDoListAPI controller it is being used like this

```
public class ToDoListController : ApiController
    {
        private string owner = "*";

        private static ITodoListDataAPINewDataAPIClient()
        {
            var client = new TodoListDataAPI(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToDoListDataAPIUrl"]));

            return client;
        }

        // GET: api/ToDoItemList
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ToDoItem>> Get()
        {
            using (var client = NewDataAPIClient())
            {
                var results = await client.ToDoList.GetByOwnerAsync(owner);
            ....
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem in this pattern is it is not testable because it directly consumes the DataAPI.

My question is, How can I make `ITodoList` to be used as dependency injection on the controller.

```
    public class ToDoListController : ApiController
    {

        private readonly ITodoListDataAPI _todoListData;

        private ToDoListController (IToDoList  todoListData)
        {
               _todoListData = todoListData;
        }
    }
```

I also don't know what Autofoca DI library to use, there is Autofac and Autofac.WebApi in the nuget gallery and I am not sure what to use in these instance.

Thanks,

Comment: Autofac - I believe, contains the core classes and interfaces. Autofac.WebApi - contains the classes required for interacting with WebApi pipeline and use injection in it.

Comment: To inject `IToDoList` into your controller you just need to setup the binding for it. Have you tried something so far?